# Rails asset directory not pointing to the directory specified in layout

Tags: javascript, css, ruby-on-rails, path, assets

In the application layout I am pointing to assets (js, css and img) in public/assets/... directory. Ex:

```
<link href='assets/images/meta_icons/apple-touch-icon-144x144.png' rel='apple-touch-icon-precomposed' sizes='144x144'>
<script src="assets/javascripts/plugins/modernizr/modernizr.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

But when the page localhost/quotes/show is loaded it is looking for the assets at quotes/assets/... and not assets/...
By the way when the page localhost/quotes is loaded, the assets are loaded perfectly and is checking in the assets/... directory and not the quotes/assets/... one

How can I solve this issue?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not use the full path to the assets directory when referencing assets from your code . Instead use `stylesheet_link_tag`, `javascript_include_tag`, `asset_path` or `image_tag` as needed. This will automatically resolve the correct path created by the Asset pipeline. See 
See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#coding-links-to-assets for a deeper explanation

Comment: Thank you. Though, I wondered if I could do it differently without using the rails framework. Any guess?

Comment: You can use asset_path, which is sprockets. http://rubydoc.info/github/petebrowne/sprockets-sass/master/Sprockets/Sass/Functions

Answer (score 0):

They make asset tag helpers, that are generally going to be required if using sprockets or anything such. Without knowing your versions, I can assume you're using Rails 4.1+.  As far as the these go, example is in SLIM.

```
= favicon_link_tag '/assets/favicon.ico'
meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"
= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all'
= javascript_include_tag 'application'
```

So as far as your example, the favicon link tag is closest. It also takes options.

Here are the documents: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper.html